# Windows 10 updates only other MS products

Tags: windows, windows-10, updates

I've installed the Creators Update on my Windows 10. I wanted to check the already installed updates and then I realized that I cannot find any Windows update only for other MS products like Office, Skype, etc (I see Quality and Other updates). Windows Update screen says my Windows is up-to-date. Is it okay or did I miss something?

Comment: Sounds like your Windows is up-to-date :) is this a domain joined machine, in that case it might search an outdated cooporate Update server (for some time)

Comment: The Skype desktop client updates are not distrubuted thrugh Windows Update.  The Skype UWP application updates would be through Windows Store.  Office 365 and Office 2016 updates are handled by Office itself

Comment: As I remember correctly on Windows 7 and 8 there was a list with Windows updates and other product updates separated.

Comment: @Panthesilea Windows 10 is different.

Comment: I've checked my PC at my workplace and I've found updates in section of 'Microsoft Windows'. The difference is that this Windows is an older one and I've already installed the latest build. I hope there is no 'Windows Update' entry because the latest build contains all of them.